# How can I resolve "Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in CakePHP" errors?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using `WAMP` server 2.4 and `CakePHP 1.2.0`. When I run my new project made in CakePHP, it gives errors like this:

- `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\crawllocal\cake\libs\debugger.php on line 196`
- `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\crawllocal\cake\libs\cake_log.php on line 68`
- `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in 
  D:\wamp\www\crawllocal\cake\libs\cake_log.php on line 182`
- `Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\crawllocal\cake\libs\inflector.php on line 300`

...etc.

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: `When I run my new project` are you really making a **new** project in 2013 with a [5 year old version of CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/18353519ed889f2e1bf4c2993ff1f20c8fa8349e)?

Answer (score 0):

That is an E_STRICT warning:

> As of PHP 5 the error reporting constant E_STRICT is available, with
>   the value 2048. When enabled, messages will be issued to warn you
>   about code usage which is deprecated or which may not be future-proof.

There are 3 ways to resolve the problem:

1. You manually edit the code. Harder, time-consuming - unreccomended.
2. You upgrade to the latest cakePHP (**2.4.4**, according to their website), where likely this issue isn't present anymore (might be painful too, but looks like yours is a quite old version, so might not be a bad idea)
3. Since the error is an E_STRICT, you change your error level not to show them:

   ```
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);  //at runtime
   ```

   or you change it in your php.ini.

Comment: Upgrading from 1.2.x to 2.x.x is _not_ a (short term) good idea; 1.x and 2.x code is quite different. Upgrading from 1.2.x to [1.3.17](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/1.3.17) however (the latest minor release of the 1.x codebase) is [relatively painless](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Appendices/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3.html) and will fix the problem in the question.